# Why aren't most voted answers displayed first?

Tags: discussion, answers, sorting

If a question has an accepted answer, this answer is displayed first --> Makes sense

However, questions without accepted answers, display them chronologically.

Than means that even if an answer has a big number of votes, it will be displayed after answers with zero votes if the latter ones are more recent.

[like this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142054/python-add-items-from-txt-file-into-a-list)

Does this make sense? It forces to scroll down looking for a good answer instead of directly presenting them.

I think that after a certain number of up-votes an answer should have some "privilege" over others, breaking the chronological order.

Comment: You can select how they're sorted. There's a tab above the list of answers. You can choose between "active", "oldest" and "votes".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a user preference

[image: Preference]

Answer (score 0):

Look at the top of the answers list. Toward the right you'll see a number of tabs: active, oldest, votes.

You've selected the "oldest" tab.

"Votes" is the default, but the setting is also "sticky". If you select "oldest on some other question, it'll stay that way for any future questions you view. Just click "votes" to go back to the view you expect.